# Jquery on PHP created HTML content from a different file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

First of all, I am a complete beginner in the matter of PHP/AJAX and sorry in advance if I did not explain something properly in the following post.

So, the long story short: I am creating a simple admin scenario in PHP/AJAX (editing users content). I cannot figure out how to act on HTML content generated through the jQuery `.post()` though.

Put in simpler words:

I have an `admin_panel.php` page that generates a dropdown list of all users. Upon dropdown selection I then use jQuery `.post()` and send a picked username to info.php to get more information about that username. Info.php echoes all queried data in a table.

Now inside of this PHP generated table (each information piece in one 'td' tag) I put an input text field that I want to act upon using another `.post()` - I want to be able for an admin to update it.

Can you guys advise me on how to make this work? I tried adding 'script' tags inside of the echoed content but it doesn't work and when I try and select echoed table from the `admin_panel.php` it also doesn't work (which is straightforward since the table is not in the source code so I cannot select an id from it).

**admin_panel.php** (only relevant stuff)

```
<select name='users' id='users'>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select user</option>
        <?php
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id <>'".$_SESSION['user_id']."'ORDER BY username DESC") or die(mysql_error());

                while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                    $username=$row['username'];
                    echo "<option value='".$username."'>".$username.'</option>';
                }

        ?>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#users').change(function(event) {
            $.post('info.php', { selected: $('#users').val() },
                function(data) {
                    $('#user_info').html(data);
                }
            );            
        }); 
        $( '#about_change' ).focusout( function(){

            $.post( "update.php?about_change=true&userid=true", {
                    about_change : $ ('#about_change').val(),
                    userid : $user_id
                },
                function( data ){
                    $('#change_about_admin').html( data );
                }
            )   
        });
    });
    </script>
```

The first `.post()` works fine. I have no clue how to approach the second one though. The "#about_change" from the second jQuery function is a content sent back from the server from the `info.php` query.

Is `update.php?about_change=true&userid=true` even correct? `$user_id` is a variable that is shown in one of the 'td' tags info.php from a "get all users" query.

**info.php** (only relevant stuff too)

```
$selected = isset($_POST['selected']) ? $_POST['selected'] : 'nothing';
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_POST['selected']."'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $user_id = $row['id'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $avatar = $row['avatar'];
    $about = $row['about'];
    $admin = $row['admin'];
}

echo("
<table id='user_table'>
<tr colspan='8'>
    <th>User ID</th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Joined</th>
    <th>Name</th>
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td>".$user_id."</td>
    <td>".$username."</td>
    <td>".$date."</td>
    <td>".$name."<br/><a class='change_admin' href='#'>Change</a></td>
</tr>
<tr colspan='8'>
    <th>About</th>
    <th>E-mail</th>
    <th>Avatar</th>
    <th>Admin</th>
</tr>
<tr colspan='8'>

    <td>".$about."<br/><a id='change_about_admin' href='#'>Change</a><br/><input type='text' id='about_change' name='about_change'></td>
    <td>".$email."<br/><a class='change_admin' href='#'>Change</a></td>
    <td><img class='avatar_small' src='$avatar' /><br/><a class='change_admin' href='#'>Delete</a></td>
    <td>");

    if(isAdmin($user_id) == 1){
        echo "Yes";
    }
    else
        echo "No";

echo ("<br/><a class='change_admin' href='#'>Change</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan='8'>
        <a href='#'>DELETE THIS ACCOUNT</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

");
```

**update.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['about_change']) && isset($_POST['uderid'])){
    $about_change = $_POST['about_change'];
    $userid = $_POST['userid'])
    echo update($userid, 'about', $about_change);
}
```

Comment: where the variable `$user_id` is defined?

Comment: You have a `uderid`, i assume it's `userid` ?

Comment: Userid is a POST variable that is suppose to carry the  $user_id  . But $user_id is only generated in the info.php.

Comment: Its gonna be a long explanation for this. You got so many flaws and bad practices in your code...I'll try my best to solve your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're trying to do is present the user with a dropdown list of users, and when selected, will display a table of that user's detail with some action that will be triggered by javascript.

My advice is, keep your files modular, its easier for you to manage.
Here's a very basic example approach to your situation, as per my understanding, with the best practice that's known to me. I hope you catch my drift.

***`users.php`***

```
<?php
    // Get your users from DB and tabulate into $userList. 
    $username = 'Example';
    $userlist = [];
    $userList .= '<option name="userID" value="$userID">'.$username.'</option>'
?>
<select id="users">
    <option selected>Select Users</option>
    <?php echo $userList; ?> <!-- This will be generated by php in the script below -->
</select>
<section id="userDetailContainer">
    <!-- This will contain the user detail table -->
</section>
// Include the javascript.
<script src="functions.js"></script>
```

***`functions.js`***

```
$(function(){
    var theURL = 'processUser.php'
    var data = {}
    $('#users').on('change', function(){
         data.command = 'displayUser'
         data.userID = $(this).val()
         $.post(theURL, data, function(result){
             $('#userDetailContainer').html(result)
         })
    })

    // This is where you assign event on dynamic contents.
    $('#userDetailContainer').on('focusout', '#username', function(e){
        data.username = $(this).val()
        data.command = 'updateUsername'
        $.post(theURL, data, function(result){
            //Do what you want with the response.
            console.log(result)
        })
    })
})
```

***`processUser.php`***

```
<?php
    //Insert MySQL here...
    if(isset($_POST['command']){
        $cmd = $_POST['command'];
        $userID = $_POST['userID'];
        $username = 'Example';
    }
    switch($cmd){
        case 'displayUser':
            // Insert your user details here. Below is an example of an input
            echo '<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Update Username" value="$username" />'
        break;
        case 'updateUsername':
            echo 'Username Updated!'
        break;
        //Insert other cases for other commands from Javascript
    }
?>
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, being a complete beginner I still need to learn how to write code efficiently using good practice. After a few modifications applied to the code it now works perfectly fine. Cheers big time!

Comment: I was once a beginner, and had a hard time looking around. Hopefully this one will help you reach further in shorter time than mine. All the best.